# Checking for a folder and file in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, file, directory

I am getting a little confused with the VBA DIR Command...
Using Windows 10 and Excel 2016 Pro.

I have an Excel file "WorkBook.xlsm", stored in folder "C:\Users\ABC", with a Worksheet named "CONFIG", with two text cells that contains respectively:

Cell G11 (text) ---> C:\Users\ABC
Cell G15 (text) ---> WorkBook.xlsm

Then...

When I try a button with a VBA code like...

```
Sub XKFile()
   Dim FileName As String
   FileName = Dir("C:\Users\ABC\WorkBook.xlsm")
   If FileName <> "" Then
       MsgBox FileName
   Else
       MsgBox "File Doesn't Exist"
   End If
End Sub
```

It works allright, I get the file name as MsgBox.

But if I try capturing the contents of both cells to compose the folder-file name...

```
Sub XKFile()
   Dim FileName As String
   FileName = Dir(ThisWorkBook.Sheets("CONFIG").Range("G11").Value & _
                  ThisWorkBook.Sheets("CONFIG").Range("G15").Value))
   If FileName <> "" Then
       MsgBox FileName
   Else
       MsgBox "File Doesn't Exist"
   End If
End Sub
```

I get the "File Doesn't Exist" message, no matter how many times I try.

And if BEFORE the DIR command, I have something like...

```
MsgBox ThisWorkBook.Sheets("CONFIG").Range("G11").Value & _
ThisWorkBook.Sheets("CONFIG").Range("G15").Value)
```

I get the correct Path+Filename written in both cells C11 and C15.

```
C:\Users\ABC\WorkBook.xlsm
```

What am I doing wrong?
Why if the Path+Filename is written in the code it works, but when the code gets them from a cell (they're plain text!), it doesn't work?

Any help would be extremely appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add ` & "\" & ` between `G11` and `G15` values

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to post it here, but there is a "\" in that place... As I said, if you write down the while path in the code, it works fine. The problem is when I pick the value of one or more fields combined and try to invoke a DIR command with that. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: >>>BOIING!!!<<< I think I had it solved... Whenever I changed the contents of any cell, the error message was constant. But, BEFORE executing the Macro, I forced a "File - Save". From then on, it worked like a charm! would that be the issue?